# Proof that every vector field on a Lie group is left-invariant

Tags: solution-verification, lie-groups, vector-fields

I am just starting a course on Lie groups and I’m having some difficulty understanding some of the ideas to do with vector fields on Lie groups.
Here is something that I have written out, which I **know** is wrong, but can't understand why:

> Let $X$ be any vector field on a Lie group $G$, so that $X\colon C^\infty(G)\to C^\infty(G)$.
> Write $X_x$ to mean the tangent vector
> $X_x\in T_x G$ coming from evaluation at $G$, that is, define
> $X_x(-)=(X(-))(x)$ for some $-\in C^\infty(G)$.
> We also write $L_g$ to mean the left-translation diffeomorphism $x\mapsto gx$.
>
> Now
> \begin{align}
>   X_g(-) &= (X(-))(g)\\
>   &= (X(-))(L_g(e))\\
>   &= X(-\circ L_g)(e)\\
>   &= X_e(-\circ L_g) \\
>   &= ((DL_g)_eX_e)(-).
> \end{align}
> Using this we can show that $((L_g)_*X)_{L_g(h)}=X_{L_g(H)}$ for all $h\in G$, and thus $(L_g)_*X=X$, i.e., $X$ is left-invariant.

I’m sure that the mistake must be very obvious, but I’m really not very good at this sort of maths, so a gentle nudge to help improve my understanding would be very much appreciated!

Comment: The passage from the first line to the second is faulty - chain rule. It looks like you are in effect writing something like that if $b = u(a)$, then $ v'( b) = ( v\circ u)'(a)$.

Comment: @peterag That's a very enlightening comment actually, makes a lot more sense when I think of what I've written like that, thanks!

Comment: Right - and $X$ has to be 'chosen correctly' to account for the (missing) chain rule of translation... As an explicit example, try out the multiplicative group $\mathbb R^*$, and $X = x d/dx$, and let $u(x) = ax$, and compare $$X_a (f) = a f'(a)$$ with $$X_1 (f \circ u) = 1 f'(a) u'(1) = f'(a) a. $$ Without the $x$ in $X$, (or scalar multiple thereof) it wouldn't have worked...

Comment: @peterag So is saying that $X$ is left-invariant sort of saying that $X$ has been 'chosen correctly', as you say? Is this a necessary and sufficient condition, or just sufficient, or neither?

Comment: It's necessary and sufficient... In the previous example, you could have chosen (erroneously) $ X=d/dx$, but then $X_a (f)= f'(a)$, while $(DL_aX)_1  (f) = a f'(a)$. So, by just looking at it, the only possible way to correct $X$ to get it to match up (i.e., be invariant under translation) is with the factor $x$... but that's precisely what you get by defining $X_a = (DL_a X)_1$. OK?

Comment: @peterag So $X$ is left-invariant if $(L_g)_*X=X$, and this is equivalent to saying that $X_h=((DL_h)_eX_e)$ for all $h\in G$? This sounds like saying that the tangent vector given by evaluation at $h$ is exactly the tangent vector given by evaluating at $e$ and then translating to $h$, but it's slightly more complicated than that due to the derivative... Any nice way of phrasing the actual result?

Comment: Oops I messed up some of the subscripts above : $(DL_a)_1 X_1$. The point is that this incorporates the necessary chain rule.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29983/discussion-between-peter-a-g-and-tim).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the equality $(X(f))(L_g(e))= X(f\circ L_g)(e)$. Note that in $(X(f))(L_g(e))$ you first get the derivative of $f$ with respect to $X$ evaluated at $g.$ But, in  $X(f\circ L_g)(e)$ you modify the function by a left translation. It holds that $(f\circ L_g)(e)=f(g)$ but you cannot say anything at nearby points, which is essential to get $X(f\circ L_g)(e)$.

Comment: Ok, so if we define $X_g=(DL_g)_e X_e$, then this doesn't align the idea of $X_g$ given by evaluation at $g$? This is the reason that I asked: the notes I'm using define $X_g$ as above, and I thought that this would be consistent with the idea of writing $X_x$ to mean the tangent vector coming from evaluation at $x$.